# NetBeans: method auto completion of the variable in expression

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete, text-editor, code-completion

I have been experiencing many difficulties using NetBeans Developer Environment, but most annoying of all that I have faced, is that new feature (I think NetBeans 7.3+), that auto completes variable with method fitting the context of expression. What I am describing, you can easily see on screenshot below.

http://s13.postimg.org/uvba2pzsn/netbeans.png
(not enough reputation to post raw image)

This is by far the most evilest thing I can imagine. Is there any reasonable way of disabling this (non)useful feature?

Also I have recently discovered another misterious force, that prevent me from writing " (quote) symbol. After pushing the quote key with shift, instead of writing ", it forces me to push another key in order for it to be displayed (usage is similar to ~ [tilde] now).

I have been on the vast majority of the websited proposed by Google, looking for similar problems. None of the solutions had application for my purposes.

I would be grateful if some kind soul could help me find resolution for this problem, because I am not enough for this. Thanks in advance.

// edit:
I am still looking for answer and I tried virtually every option. Any ideas?

AP

Comment: I am still looking for answer and I tried virtually every option. Any ideas?